# How to set a common behavior whether the subscription status has completed or errored?

Tags: typescript, http, post, rxjs

I have to update a subject that triggers a spinning wheel when a subscription has ended whether it's completed or errored.

I tried tap, do and complete but none of these working for me.

```js
http
  .post('endpoint', data)
  .subscribe(
    response => a,
    error => b
  );
```

I expect the spinning wheel to stop whatever the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Must use finalize() operator... Hm (-.-')